# Gunzip directory of files and pipe output Linux

Tags: linux, gunzip

I'd like to gunzip a directory full of compressed files and pipe the output (preserving the original files) to a different directory.  I need the original names to stay the same. So...

```
gunzip -c *.gz > file/path/filename
```

`# Search for all .gz in current directory and redirect output here.  How do I grab the name of the file found using the wildcard?`

Thank you for your help

Update: Final script below

```
FILES= /foo/bar/*.gz
for gz in $FILES; do
echo "unzipping $gz..." 1>&2
fn=$(basename $gz .gz)
gunzip -c $gz > /new/foobar/$fn
done
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Also, what do you mean by "preserving the original files"?

Comment: Apologies; just writing python, it was on the brain.  What I mean by preserving original files is that gunzip typically deletes the compressed file and outputs a file that is not compressed (hence the -c flag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a shell script instead:

```
for f in *.gz
do
    zcat "$f" > "other/folder/$(basename "$f" ".gz")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel gunzip -c {} '>' /new/foobar/{/.} ::: /foo/bar/*.gz
```

GNU Parallel takes literally 10 seconds to install:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: Installed GNU Parallel but am getting this error; `parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.` Is it a syntax problem?  Can you provide insight with the edited script in the question?

Comment: Post output of 'parallel --version'. If you did not install as mentioned above, you might be hit by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all

Comment: Installed as above; no mention of tollef `GNU parallel 20130622`

Comment: If it works with '--gnu' then you have a '--tollef' somewhere.